# Can't login with SSH and SSH host key is different when using DNS name instead of IP address

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, ssh, mac-osx

I just restarted my Ubuntu 16.04 server and started getting the error "WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!" when trying to ssh in using the DNS name `ssh me@myserver.lan`. I initially just removed the entries from known_hosts and tried again, but I realised it actually wasn't accepting my password at all.

Doing `ssh me@192.168.1.2` using the IP address still works, and even my passwordless login still works.

This is the output of `nslookup myserver.lan`, which shows the DNS is returning the correct address:

```
Server:     192.168.1.2
Address:    192.168.1.2#53

Name:   myserver.lan
Address: 192.168.1.2
```

This is the verbose output of `ssh me@192.168.1.2', which succeeds:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.2 [192.168.1.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/jimbo/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/jimbo/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/jimbo/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/jimbo/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/jimbo/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/jimbo/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/jimbo/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/jimbo/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.2:22 as 'me'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ZOO3YXwox2kHpLokBRXzPvuUFPOrposhAgnpQCaZ5+I
The authenticity of host '192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:ZOO3YXwox2kHpLokBRXzPvuUFPOrposhAgnpQCaZ5+I.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.2' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/jimbo/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.2 ([192.168.1.2]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-78-generic x86_64)
```

And this is the verbose output of `ssh me@myserver.lan`, which fails, and doesn't recognise my password:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to myserver.lan [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/jimbo/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/jimbo/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/jimbo/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/jimbo/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/jimbo/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/jimbo/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/jimbo/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/jimbo/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.9 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to myserver.lan:22 as 'me'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:WDp/1JiHcWk6Lpcgfrl+/pDbSmdFxVTZFDfVhTEqBCg
debug1: Host 'myserver.lan' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/jimbo/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/jimbo/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jimbo/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jimbo/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jimbo/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
```

As you can see the returned host keys are different. Is this correct to expect different keys when using the host name vs the IP address. What are the next steps I can take?

It looks like ssh is resolving the host name to localhost, as I get the same host key when sshing to localhost.

My hosts file is basically empty:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

But `host myserver.lan` returns this. Is this something to do with IPv6 configuration?

```
host myserver.lan
myserver.lan has address 192.168.1.2
myserver.lan has IPv6 address ::1
```

This is the output of `dig @192.168.1.2 myserver.lan`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @192.168.1.2 myserver.lan
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 32577
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;myserver.lan.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
myserver.lan.       604800  IN  A   192.168.1.2

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
myserver.lan.       604800  IN  NS  ns.myserver.lan.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns.myserver.lan.    604800  IN  A   192.168.1.2

;; Query time: 21 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.2#53(192.168.1.2)
;; WHEN: Sun May 21 13:34:41 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 79
```

And the bind config file on the server:

```
;
; BIND data file for myserver

$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     myserver.lan. root.myserver.lan. (
                              3         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
        IN      A       192.168.1.2
;
@       IN      NS      ns.myserver.lan.
@       IN      A       192.168.1.2
@       IN      AAAA    ::1
ns      IN      A       192.168.1.2
```

P.S. I have a windows laptop with cygwin which is still able to log into the server using the host name. Only my Mac seems to be affected.

Comment: According to your logs when you are connecting to myserver.lan it resolves into [::1], not 192.168.1.2

Comment: Yes, I just tried to ssh to a non existing user at localhost and got the same ssh key. So ssh is resolving the host name to localhost even though chrome and nslookup work as expected. Why would this be?

Comment: You probably have an entry for myserver.lan in your /etc/hosts file, which is ignored by nslookup

Comment: I have added some extra details, please check the post again. My hosts file is basically empty

Comment: Ping the domain name.

Comment: Can you add output of `dig @192.168.1.2 myserver.lan`? Your windows host probably doesn't have IPv6 enabled.

Comment: I think you might be on to something thanks! I added the details

Comment: @mzhaase pinging the server works fine, as do http requests. Only ssh isn't working.

Comment: You can try `-`4 command line option, but you need to remove the ::1 from the nameserver in the long run.

Comment: Remove AAAA ::1 record from your zone config file, and restart named, you are probably not using IPv6 anyway

Comment: ohhhhh I see. So I copied the localhost bind config file and accidentally didn't remove the ::1 entry. For some reason it only stopped working two days later. Facepalm. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by incorrect DNS configuration. ssh client uses IPv6 and 'myserver.lan' is being resolved to [::1] . You need to remove AAAA ::1 record from your zone configuration file and restart named.